# Yii Datefield default value

Tags: php, yii

How can I set a default date(today) value for datefield object in Yii? 
I have the following in my view.

```
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'date:'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dateField($model,'date',array('size'=>32)); ?>
```

I have tried `array('placeholder'=>'today')` as suggested [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/40216-activeform-datefield-and-default-value/) but it did not work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we are thinking about the same issue, just set `$model->date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());` before assignment in the controller.